# Google Mail Aliases or multiple Accounts?

Tags: gmail

I have a mail address addressOne@googlemail.com and would like to have a second address addressTwo@googlemail.com (Alias address) in my Google Mail Account.

I would like to add the second address as Alias to my Google Mail Account. But as far as I know, Google Mail does not support Aliases.

The alternative is to create a second Google Mail Account (with the second mail address) and import mails from one Google account to the other. But are multiple Google Mail accounts allowed to have?

What approach would you recommend to achieve having an Alias?

**Update:** The solution to use `primaryAdress+Alias@googlemail.com` proposed by @nixda is a good.

So there is no other way to set up an alias (besides creating multiple Google Mail Accounts)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> #### Using an address alias
>
> Gmail doesn't offer traditional aliases, but you can receive messages sent to your.username+any.alias@gmail.com.
>   For example, messages sent to jane.doe+notes@gmail.com are delivered to jane.doe@gmail.com.
>
> You can set up filters to automatically direct these messages to Trash, apply a label or star, skip the inbox, or forward to another email account.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en

Comment: Thank you! Mh.. On the google help page you linked, I can not see how this redirection can be done? :-(

Comment: Assuming your primary mail is `addressOne@googlemail.com`, then your alias could be `addressOne+myAlias@googlemail.com`. Every mail which is sent to the alias address will be directed to your primary mail. You don't have to set up anything. (Am I missing something obvious?)

Comment: Oh sorry, now I see how this Alias is meant to be used. I thought there has something to be set up to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I must warn you, If you plan to use alias to sign up for newsletters or to post on message boards to prevent spam from being sent to your actual email address, then don't bother! The reason I say this is because this type of alias (which is abysmal in my opinion) is useless as spammers started to recognize, and automate, the removal of the +phrase from email addresses. You should only use it to keep your work and personal email separate, even though the original purpose of alias is to defeat spammers.

P.S. It baffles me why Gmail doesn't offer traditional alias as its competitors does, but that's another topic entirely.